# Netsuite scheduled script calling API exceeds response time

Tags: netsuite

I have a scheduled script that calls and API and get's a response back that is put into a sales order. Works fine if there are less than 10 records to search but anymore and I get the following error:

{"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"SSS_REQUEST_TIME_EXCEEDED","message":"The host you are trying to connect to has exceeded the maximum allowed response time.",

The API documentation says:

> Please give us time to process your requests. If you're sending too
> many requests too quickly, we'll respond with a 429 error code
> (TooManyRequests), your application should not send any further
> requests and wait 120 secs.
>
> You are limited to only 3 or 10 requests/sec per API per account.
> Practically, this means you must (when possible) authenticate users so
> that limits are well outside the reach of a given user.

Below is my code. How can I fix this so that it waits the 120 seconds before proceeding to the next batch?

```
define(['N/search', 'N/record', 'N/https'], function(search, record, https) {

    function execute(context) {
        // Load the saved search
        var savedSearchId = 2808;
        var savedSearch = search.load({
            id: savedSearchId
        });

        // Run the search and process the results
        savedSearch.run().each(function(result) {
            // Get the Sales Order ID from the search result
            var salesOrderId = result.getValue({
                name: 'internalid'
            });
            var mawb = result.getValue({
                name: 'custbody37'
            });

            // Load the Sales Order record
            var salesOrder = record.load({
                type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
                id: salesOrderId
            });

            // Call the API with the field value from the Sales Order record and token in the header
            var fieldValue = salesOrder.getValue('custbody37');
            var url = 'https://api.XXXXXX.com/v4/XXXX';
            var headers = {
                'Tracking-Api-Key': 'XXXXXXX',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            };
            var response = https.post({
                url: url,
                headers: headers,
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    "awb_number": fieldValue
                })
            });

            log.debug({
                title: 'API Response',
                details: response.body
            });

            // Parse the response to get the value of the last_event field
            var apiResponse;
            try {
                apiResponse = JSON.parse(response.body);
            } catch (e) {
                log.error({
                    title: 'Error parsing API response',
                    details: e
                });
                return true; // continue processing search results
            }

            if (!apiResponse || !apiResponse.data || !apiResponse.data.last_event) {
                log.error({
                    title: 'API response is missing last_event field',
                    details: apiResponse
                });
                return true; // continue processing search results
            }

            var lastEventValue = apiResponse.data.last_event;

            // Update a different field in the Sales Order with the last_event value
            salesOrder.setValue({
                fieldId: 'custbody417',
                value: lastEventValue
            });

            // Save the Sales Order record
            try {
                salesOrder.save();
            } catch (e) {
                log.error({
                    title: 'Error saving Sales Order record',
                    details: e
                });
                return true; // continue processing search results
            }

            // Continue processing search results
            return true;
        });
    }

    return {
        execute: execute
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look to see if that API has a way to support larger batches or pay to increase the number of requests you're able to make. SuiteScript doesn't give you the ability to use `setTimeout` so what you're wanting to achieve isn't going to be possible without simply stopping the scheduled script and running it again later.